# Surface of revolution

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If the ellipse $x^2+x^{2/9}=1$ in the xz-plane is revolved around the $z$-axis, to find the resulting ellipsoid surface we can replace $x$ by $\pm\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. According to the book I'm using (Cracking the GRE), this gives us $x^2+y^2+\frac{1}{9}z^2=1$. My question is where does the $z$ come from?

Comment: Are you sure you meant $x^2+x^{2/9}=1$? Also, $x^2+y^2=\tfrac{1}{9}z^2$ is a cone,not an ellipsoid.

Comment: I made the edit

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a mistake in the book. It should be $x^2 + \frac{1}{9} z^2 = 1$.